# Add comment when using Paypal checkout in magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal, checkout

I want to know if there is any way to allow customers to add comments during checkout process when using Paypal checkout?. 
EDIT: this comment will show up in the sales email and order.

I found some comments modules but seems to work only with the regular checkout process!. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments for whom, going where?

Comment: to their order. to show up in the sames email like when using the regular checkout.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular checkout process"?  If your checkout is customized, it's most likely going to require a custom solution to achieve this.

Comment: @Axel i meant when the customer checkouts using credit card in the onepage checkout you will have the ability to add comment in the review section. i want the same thing when using paypal

Comment: You could add the option to add comments to an earlier step in checkout, or let them add a comment once the order has already been placed.  If you're interested in either of those 2 approaches I can try to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @MattDunbar thanks a lot.  can u give more info about adding comment after the order is placed.

Comment: @Zeedia I added a quick explanation - let me know if anything is unclear or you wanted to place it somewhere other than success.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

Adding that functionality with PayPal isn't an option, but you can add a comment after the order is placed on the thanks page.

You'll want to add a form with a text area to success.phtml, then follow the steps on the controller that it submits to.  You'll probably want to submit to a custom module.

First, get the customer's last order:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
```

Next, take that order and update its comment.

```
$order->setCustomerNote($this->getRequest()->getParam('YOUR_COMMENT_FIELD_NAME'));
$order->save();
```

If you use AJAX you can return JSON stating the note has been saved (or a validation error occurred) directly from the controller and avoid the need for a view.

If you're unsure of how to go about creating a custom module I'd recommend starting here:
http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/developing-module-for-magento-tutorial-where-to-begin-part-1

The only change I'd recommend is not echoing your output (even if it is JSON directly from the controller), but instead using something like this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('status'=>'success')));
```